# Есть ли возможность в Python сделать несколько вариантов в условии

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
   N = int(input())
   if 10 < N < 20 or (N % 10 == 5 or N % 10 == 6 or N % 10 == 7 or N % 10 == 8 or N % 10 == 9):
           print(N, 'korov')
   elif N % 10 == 1:
        print(N, 'korova')
   else:
        print(N, 'korovy')
```

Можно ли в Python как либо укоротить условие в 2 строке

Comment: `10 < N < 20 or N % 10 > 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if 10 < N < 20 or N % 10 >= 5`